# Problem with Wick contraction using Simpler-Wick

Tags: simplewick

I am trying to do to write the wick contraction between w fields of the expression below.
[image: wick]

I am using simpler-wick to do this but seems it not working. The code is given below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$$
\wick{\left[\bar{\c1 w}_{\mathcal{A}}(q)\right]^{\beta_{1}\alpha_{1}}_{n_{3}n_{4}}
\left[ \c1 w_{\mathcal{A}}(-q)\right]^{\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}}_{n_{6}n_{5}}}
$$
\end{document}
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of (a) using `\[` and `\]` instead of `$$` to initiate and terminate display math mode, (b) replacing `\bar{\c1 w}` with `\c1{\bar{w}}`, and (c) employing `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\left` and `\right` gets the job done. About not using `\left` and `\right`: I assume you were using the auto-sizing directives because you wanted to enlarge the square brackets. That's no working here, so no point in using them here.

Please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for an in-depth discussion of why one shouldn't use `$$` to initiate and terminate display math mode in LaTeX documents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\wick{\bigl[\c1{\bar{w}}_{\!\mathcal{A}}(q)\bigr]^{\beta_{1}\alpha_{1}}_{n_{3}n_{4}}\,
      \bigl[\c1 w_{\!\mathcal{A}}(-q)\bigr]^{\alpha_{2}\beta_{2}}_{n_{6}n_{5}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is now working!

Comment: @felix - You're most welcome.

Comment: @ Mico, I tried to color using \texttt{xcolor} each $w$ along with their indices while contracting but the output text is colored but without showing the contraction. Can you please put some remark fixing it?

Comment: @felix - I don't think that `\texttt{xcolor}` stands a chance at coloring `w` correctly. I experience no trouble, though, if I replace `\bar{w}` and `w` with `\textcolor{red}{\bar{w}}` and `{\textcolor{red}{w}}`. As a general principle, I think it's prudent to present an item that needs to be processed by the `simpler-wick` machinery as a single math "atom" (or should that be "molecule"?). Hence, I suggest you write `\c1{\textcolor{red}{\bar{w}}}` and `\c1{\textcolor{red}{w}}`.